# WebUSB doesn't work, connecting to micro:bit

Tags: usb, google-chrome, snap, chromium

A few years ago, I used a micro:bit on my Ubuntu 16.04. No problem.
I upgraded the machine and the OS to Ubuntu Mate 20.04 about 6 months ago. Now I want to use my micro:bit again. But I can't connect to it.

When I launch the Python editor, and I want connect to the micro:bit, I see `DAPLink CMSIS-DAP-Paired`.

When I select that, (I think it should be something else) and click on Connect, I get:

```
WebUSB Error 
Please reconnect your micro:bit and try again. 
Error: Access denied.
```

Apparently, the problem is known on the website: https://support.microbit.org/support/solutions/articles/19000105428-webusb-troubleshooting

- If Chromium has been installed from the snap store (the default in
  the Ubuntu Software Store) it will not be able to access WebUSB
  devices.

That leads me to a bug-report from the Chromium people: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1780678
The bug-report and the solution date from 2019, and the solution is said to be:

```
snap refresh chromium --channel=candidate/raw-usb 
snap connect chromium:raw-usb
```

Even though I have a more recent Chromium build, I executed the above lines, but it doesn't change a thing.

Now I don't know what to do next. I'm fine with snap packs, but if they offer less functionality, what's the use?

Some extra info: `chrome://version`

- **Chromium** 88.0.4324.150 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
- **Revision** e6c2a846b660e61f059daee2c46217af42913240-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#2103}
- **OS**   Linux
- **JavaScript**   V8 8.8.278.15
- **User Agent**   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36
- **Command Line** /snap/chromium/1479/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --password-store=basic --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation
- **Executable Path**  /snap/chromium/1479/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome
- **Profile Path** /home/jan/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default

UPDATE 24/02/2021:

1. connecting the micro:bit to a Windows 10 machine, the m:b didn't work either. But there was a message that I had to upgrade the firmware. Wich I did, following the instructions provided by micro:bit website. Now it worked on Windows, but still no go on Chromium (snap) and Ubuntu Mate.
2. another thing from the m:b website: I had to - for 'some distro's like Ubuntu ...

- create a file 50-microbit.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/ with a certain content. (on the website)
- then I had to relad the rules as: udevadm control --reload-rules
- reboot and try again.

And that didn't work.

Today, I tried my m:b on my Windows machine and it paired, as it did and as it should.
I tried it again on my Ubuntu Mate, and now it worked, also!

I have no explanaition why, but it does, so my problem is solved.

Comment: Hi @Jan80TRS did you figure out a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a persistent problem also on a recent Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with the official `google-chrome-stable` installed:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

$ dpkg -l google-chrome-stable
ii  google-chrome-stable 99.0.4844.51-1 amd64        The web browser from Google
```

The `chrome://device-log/` says `[11:08:01] Failed to open /dev/bus/usb/003/002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)`.

According to https://support.microbit.org/support/solutions/articles/19000105428-webusb-troubleshooting you can solve this with a new udev rule:

```
# Create rule
sudo cat << EOF >> /etc/udev/rules.d/50-microbit.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0d28", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
EOF

# Add current user to plugdev group
sudo usermod -a -G plugdev $USER

# Reload udev rules
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Afterwards restart Chrome and reconnect your micro:bit.

Comment: `sudo` with redirect is a tricky business. I modified your command to this `sudo bash -c 'echo SUBSYSTEM==\"usb\", ATTR{idVendor}==\"0d28\", MODE=\"0664\", GROUP=\"plugdev\" > /etc/udev/rules.d/50-microbit.rules'`

Answer (score 1):

According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1780678 I located the device address of my microbit, in my case `/deb/bus/usb/001/004`.

I changed the rights : `sudo chmod a+rwx -R /dev/bus/usb/001/004`, then I was then able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Chromium from Snap is the default, and instead of struggling with changing the default, installing the "regular" Chrome from Google with `apt` **in addition to** the answer from @timo.rieber made webusb work.